# Install an old version of MinGW GCC

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I need to compile the source code of an application that was successfully compiled using MinGW GCC 4.8.1 the last time. I tried to use the most recent version of the compiler that is available in the MinGW Installation Manager but it doesn't work.

I would like to install the 4.8.1 version but I can't find it in the packages of the Installation Manager. I tried to install it using the command line in windows after adding MinGW to Windows'

```
mingw-get install "gcc=4.8.1"
```

But it doesn't work either, some packages seem to not get found by the program and it looks like it's installing the most recent version...

Is there a way to install GCC 4.8.1 on Windows as of today ? I'm on Windows 7 pro and I'm on my computer at work so I can't go too deep in the folders and I don't have administrator rights for everything.

Thanks for your help

Comment: May I offer an alternative? Post the a distillation of the non-compiling program to a [mcve] and fix the program. This could be something as simple as a header you didn't realize you needed being removed from a header you did include or something more insidious like accidentally taking advantage of a bug in the compiler you didn't know existed to do something illegal.

Comment: @user4581301 I know this is the better solution out of the two, but what I'm talking about is a professional program that was developed over the course of 20 years and contains hundreds of thousands of lines of code spread over a hundred of .cpp and .h files. There is no way to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, not to mention that I reckon it would be illegal as the code is confidential. There is no doubt this program was poorly developed but I must deal with it unfortunately...

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm swimming in similar waters...